# What is the best way to handle unknown types in a C++ structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, interpreter, void-pointers

I'm writing an interpreter for a simple, Lisp-like programming language. It will process the code into nodes, all of them have types and some of them may have child nodes in an indexed order. Because of the difference in the nature of information, I can't use the same length of type for all node  values. The name of their type is an enum type, but the only idea I have for the type of values is `void *`. But when I use this, I must be very careful, I think. I mean, I can't use any default destructors, I must write a destructor that cares about the node type. Also I would have to use lots of casts even to access values.

This is what I'm talking about:

```
enum NodeType {/* Some node types */}

class Node
{
public:
    Node(string input_code);
private:
    NodeType type; // Having this I can know the type of value
    void* value;
};
```

Is there a way that is more secure, makes a better code but is still as efficient as usage of void pointers?

Comment: You could use a class hierarchy/inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options I can think of.  One is to use polymorphism, in which you have an abstract base class, `Node` and a number of type-specific subclasses.  Perhaps something like:

```
class Node
{
public:
  virtual ~Node() = 0;
};

class String : public Node
{
public:
  ~String() {}
};

class Float : public Node
{
public:
  ~Float() {}
};
```

When storing these nodes, you would store `Node*` rather than `void*`.  The presence of the (abstract) virtual destructor in the base class makes it possible to properly destroy concrete objects via the base class pointer, as with:

```
Node* obj = new String;
delete obj;
```

You can also call methods declared in the base class and have them execute code in the correct derived class, if those methods are virtual in the base class.  these will often also be pure virtuals, such as with:

```
class Node
{
public:
  std::string Speak() const = 0; // pure virt
};

class String : public Node
{
public:
  std::string Speak() const { return "Hello"; }
};
```

Another option is to use some kind of variant class.  C++ itself has no variant class built in to the language, but some libraries have been written such as Boost, which provide such a class.

Comment: Thanks! This is inspiring. But I cannot understand, how would that destructor know the length of memory allocated? Since it doesn't even seems to know the type itself. I'm not an experienced C++ programmer. Does C++ store the length of memory allocations in a table? Is it possible to free an allocated section of dynamic memory knowing only the pointer of the first byte?

Comment: It's all part of the magic of polymorphism.  The C++ Standard dictates that if you delete a derived class object through a base class pointer, and the base class has a `virtual` destructor, then the derived class' destructor is called.  Of course, it isn't really magic how this works, but the Standard doesn't dictate *how* it works, only that it should.  In reality most modern compilers implement this in terms of v-tables stored alongside the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use inheritance/Interfaces:

```
struct BaseNode {
    std::vector<BaseNode*> _children;
    /*Some functions here*/
}
```

For each `type` in the `enum NodeType` make a new class which inherits `BaseNode`.

Comment: This is a good idea for this way I can even throw that enum over. But how do I handle those values that aren't vectors even? Just integral types, string or something else? Because of the structure of my language, I think the simplest way would be to handle them the same as lists. (Some types of list would also evaluate to fixed-length types, but not all of them)

Comment: @kdani - I think John Dibling gives a good solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of variant type. Boost has one and details can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick sketch of a `boost::variant` based node system:

```
class Node;
struct Empty {};

// Keep enum and variant in sync:
enum NodeType {
  eEmptyNode,
  eStringNode,
  eIntNode,
  eListNode,
};
typedef std::vector< const Node > NodeList;
typedef boost::variant< std::string, int, NodeList > NodeData;

// Keep this in sync with types in Node and enum:
NodeType GetNodeType( Empty const& ) { return eEmptyNode; }
NodeType GetNodeType( std::string const& ) { return eStringNode; }
NodeType GetNodeType( int const& ) { return eIntNode; }
NodeType GetNodeType( NodeList const& ) { return eListNode; }


// Some helper code:
struct GetNodeType_visitor
{
  typedef NodeType return_type;
  template<typename T>
  NodeType operator()( T const& t ) const { return GetNodeType(t); }
};

template<typename T, typename Function>
struct OneType_visitor
{
  typedef bool return_type;
  Function func;
  OneType_visitor( Function const& f ):func(f) {}
  template<typename U>
  bool operator()( U const& u ) const { return false; }
  bool operator()( T const& t ) const { func(t); return true; }
};

struct Node
{
  NodeData data;
  NodeType GetType() { return boost::apply_visitor( GetNodeType_visitor, data ); }
  template<typename T, typename Function>
  bool Apply( Function const& func ) const
  {
    return boost::apply_visitor( OneType_visitor<T>(func), data );
  }
  template<typename T>
  Node( T const& t ):data(t) {}
  Node():data(Empty()) {}
};

// example usage:
int main()
{
  NodeList nodes;
  nodes.push_back( Node<int>( 7 ) );
  nodes.push_back( Node<std::string>( "hello" ) );
  Node root( nodes );

  Assert( root.GetType() == eListNode );
  std::function<void(Node const&)> PrintNode;
  auto PrintInt = [](int const& i) { std::cout << "#" << i; };
  auto PrintString = [](std::string const& s) { std::cout << "\"" << s << "\""; };
  auto PrintList = [&](NodeList const& list) {
    std::cout << "[";
    for (auto it = list.begin(); it !=list.end(); ++it)
    {
      if (it != list.begin()) std::cout << ",";
      PrintNode( *it );
    }
    std::cout << "]";
  }
  auto PrintEmpty = [](Empty const&) { std::cout << "{}"; }
  PrintNode = [&](Node const& n)
  {
    bool bPrinted = false;
    bPrinted = n.Apply<int>( PrintInt ) || bPrinted;
    bPrinted = n.Apply<std::string>( PrintString ) || bPrinted;
    bPrinted = n.Apply<NodeList>( PrintList ) || bPrinted;
    bPrinted = n.Apply<Empty>( PrintEmpty ) || bPrinted;
    Assert(bPrinted);
  }
  PrintNode(root);
}
```

code is not tested, but the basic idea should hold.

Note that I'm using immutable nodes, as this is for a lisp-like language.  Really I should be using `std::shared_ptr<const Node>` or something like that so two trees can share data.

`boost::variant` handles the dynamic typing problem.